# PHP OpCache optimisation

Tags: php, magento, caching, opcache

I have enabled opcode caching in php, and it delivers savings in pageloads to  the extent of 25%.

I use the excellent OpCache.php GUI tool, and my output is as below.

Keys output is as below.
[image]

Hits output is as below.
[image]

I am trying to understand some of the basic features in there.
1. What are cached keys and free keys ? 
2. How do I reduce my misses ? I read somewhere that opcache_hit_rate should be above 99%. Is there a way to go about this fine tuning. I am currently at 91% 
3. How is the visualization to be used ?

I am a beginner to this and would appreciate any help. Many thanks.

Comment: Generate a million more requests and don't update your scripts -> the hit rate will be ~99% (it's basic math isn't it?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. For technical reasons, the PHP opcode cache stores values in a fixed set of "bins", referred to here as "cache keys". The ratio of cache keys to free keys is a rough indicator of how full the cache is.
2. Your miss rate is high right now because you haven't used your application very much -- by my guess, I'd say there have been around eleven requests to your application since your web server started up. This is normal; the first few requests will always result in misses, because the files involved haven't been loaded into the cache yet.
3. Generally speaking: ignore it. Unless your application is performing poorly or misbehaving in a way that you believe is related to the cache, you don't need to look at this.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. How did you come to the 11 requests conclusion ? It is in the correct ballpark range.  Want to understand how that was estimated. Also, is the output of the tool over a period of time ? Say 24 hours or is it from the beginning of time that opcache was enabled. Thanks

Comment: The opcache stats are mostly cumulative since server startup. Your screenshot shows 7160 hits on 653 cached scripts; 7160 ÷ 653 ≈ 11.